# Trying to start Grakn but getting a Java error

Tags: java, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm trying to start Grakn with `./grakn server start` in the console. I'm in the `grakn` directory but I'm getting the error below:

```
An error has occurred during boot-up. Please run 'grakn server status' or check the logs located under the 'logs' directory.
Unsupported Java version [11] found. Grakn needs Java 1.8 in order to run.
```

Answer (score 1):

Grakn uses Java 8 whereas you have Java 11. You can fix this by installing the JDK for Java 8, you should be able to find it for your system [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html).

Then, you need to make sure Java 8 can be found. On mac/unix:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```